# WebApi MessageHandler parameter type issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i am trying to decrypt the id available in http url using Messagehandler. Even though i am getting url correct after decryption.

Url before decryption http://localhost:ip/v1/controller/abcd

Url after decryption http://localhost:ip/v1/controller/1

Below is the logic of my MessageHandler.

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(); 
string replacedParam = querySegment.Replace("/", ""); 
builder.Path = builder.Path.Replace(replacedParam, Cryptor.DecryptString(replacedParam));
request.RequestUri  = builder.uri;

HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

At Controller end, route is  expecting id parameter of type integer. Even though MessageHandler changes the Encryption Key to integer value but still End Point is not being called.

```
[Route("{id}")]
[HttpGet]
ResponseType(typeof(ChannelViewModel))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetByIdAsync([FromUri]int id)
```

Error :
"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System".

if i call route with integer parameter it works fine . but if i call route with encrypted key and MessageHandler changes the key to integer value , route still considers it a string while handler sending it integer value. Same MessageHandler working fine with my other two projects. But could not find issue in this one.

Comment: Where and how are your registering your handler? Are you setting it per route in webapi.config?

Comment: @Ren MessageHandler is being registered globally.